# How to fix "List index out of range" error while extracting the first and last page numbers in my web-scraping program?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to create my first Python web-scraper to automate one task for work - I need to write all vacancies from this website (only for health) to an Excel file. Using a tutorial, I have come up with the following program.

However, in step 6, I receive an error stating: `IndexError: list index out of range`.

I have tried using `start_page = paging[2].text`, as I thought that the first page may be the base page, but it results in the same error.

Here are the steps that I followed:

1. I checked that the website https://iworkfor.nsw.gov.au allows scraping
2. Imported the necessary libraries:

   ```
   import requests  
   from bs4 import BeautifulSoup  
   import pandas
   ```
3. stored the URL as a variable:

   `base_url = "https://iworkfor.nsw.gov.au/nsw-health-jobs?divisionid=1"`
4. Get the HTML content:

   ```
   r = requests.get(base_url)` 
   c = r.content
   ```
5. parse HTML

   `soup = BeautifulSoup(c,"html.parser")`
6. To extract the first and last page numbers

   ```
   paging = soup.find("div",{"class":"pana jobResultPaging tab-paging-top"}).find_all("a")  

   start_page = paging[1].text  

   last_page = paging[len(paging)-2].text
   ```
7. Making an empty list to append all the content:

   `web_content_list = []`
8. Making page links from the page numbers ,crawl through the pages and extract the contents from the corresponding tags

   ```
   for page_number in range(int(start_page),int(last_page) + 1):   

       # To form the url based on page numbers  
       url = base_url+"&page="+str(page_number)  

       r = requests.get(base_url+"&page="+str(page_number))  

       c = r.content  

       soup = BeautifulSoup(c,"html.parser")
   ```
9. To extract the Title

   `vacancies_header = soup.find_all("div", {"class":"box-sec2-left"})`
10. To extract the LHD, Job type and Job Reference number

    `vacancies_content = soup.find_all("div", {"class":"box-sec2-right"})`
11. To process vacancy by vacancy by looping

    ```
    for item_header,item_content in zip(vacancies_header,vacancies_content):

       # To store the information to a dictionary
       web_content_dict = {}
    web_content_dict["Title"]=item_header.find("a").text.replace("\r","").replace("\n","")
       web_content_dict["Date Posted"] = item_header.find("span").text

       web_content_dict["LHD"] = item_content.find("h5").text

       web_content_dict["Position Type"] = item_content.find("p").text

       web_content_dict["Job Reference Number"] = item_content.find("span",{"class":"box-sec2-reference"}).text

      # To store the dictionary to into a list
       web_content_list.append(web_content_dict)
    ```
12. To make a dataframe with the list

    `df = pandas.DataFrame(web_content_list)`
13. To write the dataframe to a csv file

    `df.to_csv("Output.csv")`

Ideally, the program will write the data about all vacancies to a CSV file in a nice table with the columns: title, date posted, LHD, Position Type, Job reference number.

Comment: Thanks. I am trying to scrape page like this one https://iworkfor.nsw.gov.au/nsw-health-jobs?divisionid=1. This is only the first page.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your initial call to `find()` returns an empty `<div>`, and so your subsequent call to `find_all` returns an empty list:

```
>div = soup.find("div",{"class":"pana jobResultPaging tab-paging-top"  
>div  
   <div class="pana jobResultPaging tab-paging-top">  
   </div>  
>div.find_all("a")
[]
```

Update:

The reason you're unable to parse the contents of the `<div>` in question (i.e. why it's empty) has to do with the fact that the data retrieved from the server is "paginated" by client-side javascript (code in your browser). Your python code is parsing only the HTML that is returned by the request to `iworkfor.nsw.gov.au`; the data that is what you're after (and what is turned into "pages") is requested by that same javascript and returned by the server in a format called `JSON`.

So, the bad news is that the instructions that have been provided to you will not work. You will have to parse the JSON returned by the server and then decode the escaped HTML that it contains.

Comment: Thanks heaps! I see that it is much more complicated than I thought :-(, would you be able to point me into the right tutorial, post or course that explains this?

Comment: Hi, chb. I am learning about json but I am still too far from my destination. If you don't mind, I can use some help. Thanks!

Comment: @ElenaHeart Were you to [accept the answer I've provided](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer), I'd be happy to elaborate further.